# Como retornar apenas o registro correspondente a busca SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Criei um sistema básico de consulta, para que os clientes do meu site consigam saber o status do seu pedido. Está funcionando diretinho, porém ao digitar um valor que não seja o código do pedido ele acaba retornando todos os registros que estão na tabela.

Exemplo: o cliente digita o número 1, ele lista todos os pedidos que contenham 1 no código.

Gostaria de retornar apenas 1 registro desde que o código seja exato ao que tenho no BD e não todos os registros que contenham tal número ou então limitar a exibição para apenas 1 registro.

Código do meu arquivo principal de busca:

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control" name="pedido" id="codigo" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['pedido'])) echo $_GET['pedido']; ?>" placeholder="Código do pedido" type="tel" autocomplete="off" required >
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 15px;">Verificar</button>
</form>
</center>
<br>
<table class="table table-sm">
    <tr>
        <th>Pedido</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_GET['pedido'])) {
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Digite o código do seu pedido para verificar...</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    } else {
        $pesquisa = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['pedido']);
        $sql_code = "SELECT * 
            FROM ws_pedidos 
            WHERE codigo_pedido LIKE '%$pesquisa%' 
            OR codigo_pedido LIKE '%$pesquisa%'
            OR status LIKE '%$pesquisa%'";
        $sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die("ERRO ao consultar! " . $mysqli->error); 
        
        if ($sql_query->num_rows == 0) {
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><b>Nenhum pedido encontrado...</b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        } else {
            while($dados = $sql_query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $dados = str_replace("%20"," ", $dados);
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>#<?php echo $dados['codigo_pedido']; ?></b></td>
                    <td><?php echo $dados['nome']; ?></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $dados['status']; ?></b></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    <?php
    } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: "e não todos os registros que contenham tal número" – mas então por que usou LIKE e % ?

Comment: Se deixar em branco vem tudo porque LIKE '%%' é sempre verdadeiro.

Comment: Obrigadoo! Ainda não tenho muita noção de SQL, removi o %% e está perfeito. Vlw

Comment: Use igual, (=) em vez de like

Answer (score -1):

Acho que se vc tirar o '%' do %$pesquisa% vai funcionar,
o símbolo % ele vai pesquisar tudo que tenha esse valor:

Exemplo:

```
  WHERE nome LIKE %nome%
```

E se você tiver digitado  a letra L
ele vai buscar todos os nomes com L, (Lucas, Alessandra, Alex)
se você tirar o % ele vai pesquisar exatamente o que você digitar.

Mas ai vai ter que pesquisar o nome completo,
**WHERE** nome **LIKE** nome
você vai ter que  pesquisar 'Lucas' e vai receber Lucas de retorno,
se pesquisar só 'L' não vai receber nada

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).